# Springbootの@JsonPropertyで指定したキーでJSONを返したい

Tags: json, spring-boot

◆Controller

```
@RestController
@ResponseBody
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TestDto> test(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString())

        TestDtoリストを取得する

        return dto;
    }
}
```

◆DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -xxxxxxxL;

    private String TestName;

    private String TestComment;

}
```

◆JSON

```
{
  {
    "testName": "testA",
    "testComment": "testAです"
  },
  {
    "testName": "testB",
    "testComment": "testBです"
  }
}
```

上記のようにJSONにはなるものの、キーの先頭が小文字になっていたため、以下を参考にDTOを変更しました。
http://blog.soushi.me/entry/2016/12/29/134940

◆DTO

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;★
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class TestDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -xxxxxxxL;

    @JsonProperty("TestName")★
    private String TestName;

    @JsonProperty("TestComment")★
    private String TestComment;
}
```

そうすることでキーは「@JsonProperty」で指定した値で取得できるようになったのですが、
JSON内に先頭が小文字のものと「@JsonProperty」で指定したものの二通りが取得できるようになってしまいました。
「@JsonProperty」の使い方でなにか悪い箇所がありますでしょうか？

◆JSON

```
{
  {
    "TestName": "testA",
    "TestComment": "testAです",
    "testName": "testA",
    "testComment": "testAです"
  },
  {
    "TestName": "testB",
    "TestComment": "testBです",
    "testName": "testB",
    "testComment": "testBです"
  }
}
```

Comment: 挙動から察するに、Jacksonが「フィールド名」と、(lombokにより自動生成されている)「getter」の双方からJSONシリアライズ対象を決定しているように見受けられます([こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105745/how-to-specify-jackson-to-only-use-fields-preferably-globally)によるとおそらくこの推測は正しいかと)。Spring上での設定は私には分からないのですが([前述リンク先](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13495327/4506703)の通り、Jacksonへは`ObjectMapper#setVisibility`メソッドで設定可能)、フィールドアクセスのみでJSONシリアライズを行うようにすれば解消するのではないでしょうか。([Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean を設定？](https://qiita.com/dayflower/items/67503dbe3157d13db547))

Comment: yukihaneさま　ありがとうございます
ひとまず、lombokが影響しているのかを判断したく、DTOのクラスから、lombokの記載（アノテーション）を削除し、getter/setterを用意してみました。すると期待値のJSONを取得できました！
ですので、次は教えていただいたリンク先の記載を試してみたいと思います。